# Java Eclipse with MS SQL server 2008

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-server-2008

I started learning c# with the use of MS SQL server 2008, I'm just wondering if I could implement the 3 layered in jsp?

I will have my Data access layer where my connections and methods like (add,delete,view,update) and so on with the Business logic and for the UI.

I tried to do it but it can't display the output. I tried a simple one of adding then viewing the added ones. (No business logic yet)

Here is my code:

public class DAL {

```
public static String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
static String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; database = Sample; Integratedsecurity = true";


public void addProduct(String productName){
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

            String sql = "Insert into Products values (?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, productName);
            pst.closeOnCompletion();
            pst.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ResultSet viewProduct(){
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        String sql = "Select * from Products";

        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            rs.getInt(2);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;  
}
```

Here is my page where it add the products from the user (i just cut the other parts of html)

```
<%!
    DAL d = new DAL();
%>

<body>
<% 
    String productName = request.getParameter("productName") != null ?   
        request.getParameter("productName") : "No product has been delivered";
    d.addProduct(productName);
%>
<h1> Product: <%= d.viewProduct() %> </h1>
</body>
```

The errors says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` but I have in my classPath the library and I tried not to have a 3 tier just for testing purposes but yet it still not working. The return is Null and classnotfoundexception. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues in your code:

- The `addProduct()` call is missing an `pst.executeUpdate()` method on the statement. So, the insert will never be run.
- The `viewProduct()` call is not closing the obtained `ResultSet`, this results in dangling resources in the JDBC driver and possibly even on the SQL-server.
- You can manage all calls using one connection, no need to open a new one every run. Besides that, you are not closing the connections after use. You should use the new Java syntax for try-with-resources or add a finally block:

  ```
   try ( Statement st = connection.prepareStatement(sql); )
   {
       // use the statement here ...
       st.executeUpdate();
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
   }
   // st will be closed here


  Statement st = null;
  try
  {
     st = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
  }
  finally {
      try { 
          if( st != null ) st.close(); 
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) {
           throw new RuntimeException("cannot close statement", ex);
      }
  }
  ```

The general approach is very hackish. If this is to be a JSP based application, you should consider a connection pool instead of handling the connections on a per call basis. The connection pool is configured as a Datasource in your web.xml and needs to be configured according to the container you are using (Tomcat, Jetty, ...).

If you are using a container datasource, you will draw the connection from the datasource, not from the JDBC driver directly. Otherwise, you should consider a connection pool inside your application, that provides a ready-made connection to you on request.

Having said this:

Where do you place the jar file for the SQL driver? The way you call it, it should be in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand clearly you. I'm still learning the basics of it. But as far as I can understand it, I made a user library where I called it JDBC and imported the jar file which is sqljdbc4.jar. Then why would I be having an classnotfoundexception?

Comment: How do you run your application? As it is a JSP, you must have some kind of a container.

Comment: I am running my web application through eclipse, apache tomcat v8

Comment: if you export to a war file (a ZIP archive in disguise), you should find the sqljdbc4.jar in the web-inf/lib folder, if it is not there, the problem is in the way you configured the class-path. You may want to try a static class or unit test to run your DAL. If that works correctly, you have a deployment issue. If the test-application doesn't work, you need to fix that first.

Comment: It is not there when I export it in a war file? do i need to copy & paste the jar file into the web-inf/lib folder in my eclipse?

Comment: I have a deployment issue. Because I tried the given code by Etienne Ghigo and it works in a simple java class but not in the jsp.

Comment: "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication" but when on the sample java class it works same connection url. Why is that?

Comment: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication

Comment: This is the missing DLL for single sign on. You need to install the driver with the correct native dll or better, for now, use the username and password in the jdbc url. If you google for the error, you will find similar problems immediately.

Comment: But why when I use it in another simple java class? It works without problem?

Comment: Because the dll is not found in the tomcat environment, yet, it can be found in your standalone app environment. This may have to do with search paths in the eclipse application runner. Those paths are different when running in the application server. You may add a `-Djava.library.path=<path to dll>` to the JVM options panel of the Tomcat runtime configuration. But chances are, that some other required library is not found then. As you are just learning, you should take one after the other. Use a SQL login for now, if you get that running, configure the SSO dll.

Comment: And don't miss the chance to upvote the answers that helped you - people invested time to help you out, you give them upvotes in return.

Comment: Okay now I get the difference and the situation I am encountering. I will what you've suggested. Can I retrieve my username and password in sql login? I forgot what i've inputted there. Anyways, thank you so much for your time. Really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, you can always add another user if you forgot the old one. Or login with your current windows user and reset the password for the sql user. I don't know too much about the users management on sql-server but you may try to use your windows credentials for login, a quick check on SO will help here, too. :-)

Comment: Heyy!!! It works using the SQL login! So now I know what is my problem :) Thank you!

Comment: Cool. To make SO an even better place to find answers, feel free to update your question with the now working code, and what you did to make it happen. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to make sure is that the sqlserver library is correctly set in the build path. To access/update/delete entries from your database, try the following:

```
Connection conn = null;

Statement stmt = null;

try {

    // Register JDBC driver
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);

    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String sql = "Enter your update query";

    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    // Extract all the records to see the updated records
    sql = "Enter your select query";

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    while (rs.next()) {

        // Retrieve data by column name in your database
        String username = rs.getString("enter relevant column name from database");

        int logintries = rs.getInt("enter relevant column name from database");

        // Display values to console
        System.out.print("Username : " + username);

        System.out.print(", Login Tries : " + logintries);

    }

    rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException se) {

        se.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

If the ms sqlserver library is set correctly, this should work for you too. Hope it helps...

Comment: Check the following link maybe it can help you up to set your build paths : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx